# Unable to Like a post from ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

i am using Facebook SDK 3.0  to login user and i am successfully getting its FB id and FB session token.

```
`NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user.id` (FB ID)
```

and 
    `[FBSession.activeSession accessToken]` (FB session token)

Now i want to like a post inside  my app. SO i am creating a POST request and passing the parameters like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/og.likes",@"34856345..."]] cachePolicy:NO timeoutInterval:5.0];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"BAAGjjgD8bhUBAM73jzkpy23zlHo7e8ZAqPaOGvbxU..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];
    [urlRequest addValue:myshareLink forHTTPHeaderField:@"object"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [theConnection autorelease];
```

but i am getting this error

```
 result:{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

but if i use the same access token and user id from CURL command it posts successfully.

```
curl -X POST -F 'access_token=BAAGjjgD8bhUBAE8XmogjJZAZAPyJ8SUyxkllJQ...' -F 'object=http://xyz.com/abc/gallery.php#pic/pic2/' https://graph.facebook.com/732../og.likes
```

Please some help me figure it out what i am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the FBRequestConnection and FBRequest class found in the iOS Facebook SDK rather than using NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequest. I believe Facebook requires some extra header values at the iOS level that the Facebook SDK automatically generates for you.

For a like action, I used the FBRequest class method requestForGraphPath to create the request. Don't forget to set the httpMethod and session fields on your FBRequest before passing it to a FBRequestConnection.